# Can't install Vue CLI? (MacOS)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, terminal, vuejs2

Hey so I'm trying to install Vue via npm (`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`) and I just get a bunch of warnings and errors and I can't really make sense of it and have no idea why its happening...

> ```
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see [`https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142`](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: [`https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated`](https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated)
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see [`https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated`](https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated)
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
>
> /usr/local/bin/vue -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
> > fsevents@1.2.13 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents`
> > node install.js
> gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/jamesecroyd/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0"
> gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp"
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'
> gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents
> gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
> ```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?
I have installed and uninstalled Vue multiple times, no luck...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use NPM's [`--unsafe-perm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm) flag:

```sh
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli --unsafe-perm
```

Or switch to a Node version manager (e.g., [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n)), which avoids these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my Mac install this way:

1. Uninstalled vue cli first.

`sudo npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`

2. Re-installed with **added switch** to deal with file access issue.  Which gives some warnings, but no errors.

`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli --unsafe-perm`

3. Also then, installed the dependency in the warning that printed out at the very end of the install in Step 2.

`sudo npm install -g vue@3.0.0-rc.9`

After step 3, a "vue --version" command prints "@vue/cli 4.5.4" at this point, but it would do that previously.

So for a real test, I created a new project in the vue ui, which took much longer (30+ seconds) than my original first project created after the original troubled vue cli install.

And that **new project works!** -- I clicked "serve" in the Tasks window, can see a clean build in the Output window, and the demo page loads at `http://localhost:8080/` like it supposed to! Welcome to Your Vue.js App, etc...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem
just run this command

> sudo npm uninstall -g @vue/cli

first check you have installed npm and node