# Vue3 install with _FSEventStreamCreate error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have been using Vue2 for study and now moving to Vue3.  I uninstalled Vue2 on my Mac:

```
npm uninstall vue-cli -g
```

I then installed Vue3:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I checked the vue version:

```
(base) Tims-iMac-Pro-4:project_one tim$ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.8
```

Created a project:

```
vue create project_one
cd project_one
```

But then get this error when attempting to run the server:

```
(base) Tims-iMac-Pro-4:project_one tim$ npm run serve

> project_one@0.1.0 serve /Users/tim/Google Drive/Vue Dev/Vue3_1/project_one
> vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...
10% building 2/2 modules 0 activedyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: 
_FSEventStreamCreate
 Referenced from: /Users/tim/Google Drive/Vue Dev/Vue3_1/project_one/node_modules/webpack- 
 dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
 Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
Referenced from: /Users/tim/Google Drive/Vue Dev/Vue3_1/project_one/node_modules/webpack- 
dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
Expected in: flat namespace

Abort trap: 6
(base) Tims-iMac-Pro-4:project_one tim$
```

Still investigating what the _FSEventStreamCreate error is and what I have done incorrectly but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Applied the solution in this post but it did not resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62494949/cant-install-vue-cli-macos

Comment: for vue3, I've been using vite, which is very nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I installed the latest version of Nodejs from here and it now works.
https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Had the same problem. Installing the latest version of Node.js did the trick for me as well.