# Vue CLI not installing

Tags: vue.js, installation

I'm attempting to install the Vue CLI with the following command **npm install -g @vue/cli**.

I get the following output from the terminal:

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'

changed 1412 packages, and audited 1413 packages in 26s

61 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I then run **vue --version** and get the following output:

```
zsh: command not found: vue
```

Im using NPM v 7.5.1.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this one can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62495033/8816585

`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli --unsafe-perm`
or maybe try to install it with yarn: `yarn global add @vue/cli`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion, I have unfortunately already tried this!

Comment: What happened there ?

Comment: Same issue, still said command not found. I ended up getting around it using npx instead of npm. Thanks again!